# How would you go about testing partial, RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Lets say I have a very complicated view with a very complicated test spec.
I would like add another feature to it and I would like to drive the development with RSpec.

I would like to add contacts to Employee class.

Somewhere in the employee.html.erb I add the line:

```
#lots of data rendered so far

<%= render @employee.contacts %>

#even more here
```

At the moment I don't really know what `_contact.html.erb` partial needs to look like. To test it directly from my main view spec for employees, `show.html.erb_spec.rb`, I would have to do a lot of set up populating or mocking different database employee is build from(projects, departments etc.).

All I need to test for now is that partial, I don't care about departments, projects and other things this employee currently belongs to and I don't want to spend my time on mocking them all up. I will probably add it to my main spec later on and create everything needed to test the entire view but not just jet.

Do you have any technique or way for creating an instance of Employee, adding a few Contacts to it, and testing the view for just the partial? 
Without worrying about all the other things the Employee is built from.

**UPDATE FOR IGEL ANSWER:**

I agree with you, and testing for expect(...).to receive(:render) is 100% enough for request spec and I would go no further if I already had a partial template.
I just wanted to go extreme and drive my div's and span's through RSpec. Not testing for behaviour of new feature but it look. Do you suggest its not worth it?

I don't test views(structure) at all but I have seen a few documents like [Rails Tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/) where Michael is not only testing behaviour but as well structure. I thought I'll give it a go:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to avoid very complicated views. If there is almost no logic in the view, then there is maybe no need to test it. Extract the logic into [presenters](http://robertomurray.co.uk/blog/2014/decorators-presenters-delegators-rails/), that way it's much easier to test. I don't test my views with view tests, because maintaining them it usually not much fun. Some feature specs give me enough security here.

If you still want to test it, you would probably expect that `render` was called with the expected arguments:

```
expect(view).to receive(:render).with(@employee.contacts)
```

Not sure if the view is available via `view`.

PS: Don't just avoid to write complicated views, avoid complicated code. This is really hard, but also absolutely worth the time. Almost every developer can hack together something probably working, but creating something easy to understand and to change will help everybody including your future you. Code is read ten times more often than it is written/changed, so we have to optimize for that.

> I didn't have time to write a short letter, so I wrote a long one instead.
>   -- Mark Twain

Comment: I have updated a question with clarification why I would like to test it.